# Cloud Watch Threshold alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

We have set Amazon CloudWatch Alarm if the threshold value for `CloudFront5xxAlarm` is more than 5.0 we receive email from Amazon CloudWatch Alarm:

> Threshold Crossed: 3 datapoints [11.43415057496203 (18/05/20 10:53:00), 6.422018348623853 (18/05/20 10:48:00), 8.23231650459571 (18/05/20 10:43:00)] were greater than the threshold (5.0).

Is there a way to spot what failed from CloudWatch Logs or from the CloudFront access logs?

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to access the CloudFront access logs.

Comment: But how do we identify this particular issue in CloudFront access logs?

Comment: Find the 5XX error, validate whether it was CloudFront or your application. IF it was CloudFront then look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-response-errors.html

Comment: I see too many 5xx errors on cloud front access logs. How can I find the above threshold? So that I can concluded this the reason for the issue.